# How Activity.finish() & startActivityForResult() collaborate with each other?

Tags: android, android-activity

I got a question about `Activity.finish()`.

In my Android code, there are 4 activities (**A**, **B**, **C**, **D**). The starting activity **A** calls `startActivityForResult(intent, reqCode)` to start activity **B**. **B** starts **C**, and then `finish()`, not waiting for result. **C** does exactly the same as **B**, starts **D** and then `finish()`. **D** will return some result, by `setResult(resultCode)`.

When my code runs and activity **D** returns some result, **A** will catch a `RESULT_CANCELED` on `onActivityResult()`, even if `RESULT_OK` is returned in **D**. I guess the `RESULT_CANCELED` is from activity **B**, which has been terminated before **D** returns a result, rather than from **D**.

But, my question is, why activity **A** catch `RESULT_CANCELED` after **D** returns some result, rather than immediately after **B** is terminated? And, what should I do to make **A** catch results from **D**? Do I have to keep **B** and **C** alive, to pass results from **D** to **A**?

Comment: Yes you would have to keep B and C alive . You can finish() them once they have received result and passed it on. Example you can finish C once it has received result from D and passed it on to B. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks. Keeping B and C alive really works for me, but it also brings more codes to handle the result passing. Is it possible for A to receive from D directly? Another question is, why activity A catch RESULT_CANCELED after D returns some result? If A get results from B, it should get the result immediately after B is finished, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

From your explanation, i understood that activity **A** starts **B** starts **C** and **C** starts **D**.

**B** after starting **C** invokes `finish()` and **C** also does the same.

Since **B** has been started by **A**, it will be waiting for result from **B**, as **A** has not been linked to **D**, it doesn't matter even if **D** returns some result.

If you want to get `RESULT_OK` in `onActivityResult()` of **A**, you will have to receive valid result from **B**.
For that you have to receive **D**'s result in **C** then pass it to **B** then from **B** pass it to **A**.

You can invoke `finish()` in `onActivityResult()` of **B** and **C** after passing result back to their respective calling activities through Intent.

I think, I understood your question correctly. If its wrong, please forgive me.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please refer to my feedback to Shahab, and I got 2 further questions.

Answer (score 2):

Start activity **B** and **C** with flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT` .

Answer (score 0):

May this wont be too sensible,
but why dont you `**set result of B and C to RESULT_OK**` depeding on some situation evaluation. I hope